# How can i make a datePicker show the date on a textField?

Tags: ios, date, datepicker, datefield

I have a textField in my view and under it a picker.

I need when the user chooses a date from the datePicker the textField to show the exact value of the date.

How do i get the date from the dateField?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the value_changed event of your DatePicker to a IBAction :

example :

```
- (IBAction) dateChanged:(id)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    self.currentTextField.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[self.datePicker date]];
}
```

Comment: Hey I know you M. Daubry :)

Comment: It's probably better to set the date formatter's style to something like `NSDateFormatterMediumStyle` instead of hardcoding a format.

Comment: @rmaddy : following your comment, you're just right, i edited my answer

Comment: @Dirty Henry : small world ;)

Comment: @vdaubry I think you have it backwards. The whole point to setting the style instead of a hardcoded format is that the style is properly shown based on the user's locale.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a method to update the date changed from the `UIDatePicker` by setting an action to `Value Changed` event in the connection inspector, implement the action to set the value to textField something like this

```
- (IBAction)datePickerValueChanged:(id) sender{

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;

    self.textfield.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];

}
```

OR you could add selector to the `UIDatePicker`

```
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateMyDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIDatePicker` has a `date` property. You can access the `NSDate` via this property.

Then you probably need to use `NSDateFormatter` to create a `NSString` from your `NSDate`, and be able to display it in your `UITextField`.

In its most straightforward way, your code should look like this:

```
myTextField.text = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:myDatePicker.date];
```

Comment: Add that there is an event that can be used to get notified when a user makes a selection.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateFormat = "dd-MMMM-yyyy hh:mm a"

    //To show date in textfield     

    myTextField.text = [df stringFromDate:datePicker.date];

    //To show selected date on datepicker from textfield 

   datePicker.date = df.dateFromString(myTextField.text)
```